# Get value from List based on match condition

Tags: c#

I have a list : `var abc = {"Apple", "Orange"};`

I also have a string : `var def = "{[Mountain, Mountain, Apple ]}";`

I am able to check if the value is true or false with the below code

```
bool ghi = abc.Any(s => def.Contains(s));
```

**How do I get the position or index in abc though ?**

Answer (score 1):

You can eiher implement `for` loop or put something like this:

```
int index = Enumerable
  .Range(0, abc.Count)
  .FirstOrDefault(i => def.Contains(abc[i]), -1);
```

Or even less readble but works with `IEnumerable<string>` not necessary `List<string>`:

```
int index => abc
   .Select((item, idx) => (item, idx))
   .FirstOrDefault(pair => def.Contains(pair.item), (null, -1))
   .idx;
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would **NOT** ask for the position. Instead, you want the elements, which you can do like this:

```
var result = abc.Where(s => def.Contains(s));
```

Now `result` has the items (all of them) that match.